# Merge arrays by id and account for unique values with duplicate associative indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays structured like so:

```
Array
(
    [platform] => Nintendo
    [console] => Nintendo NES
)
1
Array
(
    [platform] => Nintendo
    [console] => Super Nintendo
)
1
Array
(
    [platform] => Nintendo
    [console] => Nintendo 64
)
1
Array
(
    [platform] => Nintendo
    [console] => Gamecube
)
Array
(
    [platform] => Atari
    [console] => Atari 2600
)
1
Array
(
    [platform] => Atari
    [console] => Atari 5200
)
1
Array
(
    [platform] => Atari
    [console] => Atari 7800
)
Array
(
    [platform] => Sega
    [console] => Sega Master System
)
1
Array
(
    [platform] => Sega
    [console] => Sega Genesis
)
1
Array
(
    [platform] => Sega
    [console] => Sega CD
)
```

I'd like to merge the consoles into an array under their respective platforms and understand how to do it with unique indexes but not where they are the same. My desired output would be like so:

```
Array
(
    [Nintendo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nintendo NES
            [1] => Super Nintendo
            [2] => Nintendo 64
            [3] => Gamecube
        )

    [Atari] => Array
        (
            [0] => Atari 2600
            [1] => Atari 5200
            [2] => Atari 7800
        )

    [Sega] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sega Master System
            [1] => Sega Genesis
            [2] => Sega CD
        )

)
```

I tried the following:

```
$new = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  if(is_array($value)){
    if( !array_key_exists($value['platform'],$new) ){
        $new[$value['platform']] = [];
    }  
    $new[$value['platform']] = array_merge($new[$value['platform']], $value );
  }
}
```

Yet it only returns the last console in each platform because they don't have unique console ids. Would this require a regex to look for matching platform names and non-matching console names? Am I even going in the right direction or should I look to `array_reduce` or `array_walk`?

Comment: @NigelRen wow, that is super simple and it will serve my purpose. Thank you very much for taking the time to read and comment! If you'd like to make that into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you check if it's an array in the loop, you can remove that part and then just add in the console to the existing list using `[]`...

```
$new = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if( !array_key_exists($value['platform'],$new) ){
        $new[$value['platform']] = [];
    }  
    $new[$value['platform']][] = $value['console'] ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The check is what I learned to do in another answer but this bit makes it very clear what's going on. I'll accept it as the answer once it's unlocked.

Comment: You don't need the `if` at all.